# Previous Value of Measure inside a Tuple in an MDX query

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssas, mdx

I have the following MDX query inside a report:

```
select 
({ [Measures].[Total]})   on columns,
non empty
[Dim1].[h1].allmembers
* [Dim1].[h2].allmembers
* [Dim1].[h3].allmembers
* [1 Date - Loss Date].[Date].[Year].allmembers
having [Measures].Total>100000 on rows
from [Monthly Summary]
where ([1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120331])
```

This is selecting rows with the Total value of more than 100k in March. How would I select the rows with Total value of more than 100k ***either in March or February*** meaning get the result from the above query **plus** the result of this month values where the *previous* month is more than 100k ?

Right now, I'm doing this in two Datasets in SSRS and doing a join and lookup of one on the other and the month (the Where Clause) is read from a Report Parameter; which is close nut not correct.

**Update:** Weather the [Total] value in March is more than 100k or the [Total] value in February is, I need to see the March Total Value in the query result( which might be less than 100k in second scenario)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
SELECT ({ [Measures].[Total]}) ON COLUMNS,
[Dim1].[h1].allmembers
* [Dim1].[h2].allmembers
* [Dim1].[h3].allmembers
* [1 Date - Loss Date].[Date].[Year].allmembers
HAVING [Measures].[Total] > 100000
OR ([Measures].[Total], [1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120228]) >100000 
ON ROWS
FROM [Monthly Summary]
WHERE ([1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120331])
```

You do not need the non emtpy on the rows because `null < 100000`

Comment: Thanks for the answer Benoit. I'm sorry I didn't clearly specify my requirements. In case of "previous" [total]>100k I still need to see the "current" [total] (that might be less than 100k). This query gives the total values  more than 100k either in current month or previous month.

Comment: @FrankGoortani I updated my query so that it displays the total in march (which is the current total)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirement, you want rows for the month in the where clause or the month prior to the one in the where clause for which the total is over 100K. The where clause is going to affect the value that you see for the Total measure so you can't leave it in the where clause if you want to see the prior month's value, too. To see whether the row is for March or for February, you must include it in rows  like this:

```
select 
({ [Measures].[Total]})   on columns,
non empty
[Dim1].[h1].allmembers
* [Dim1].[h2].allmembers
* [Dim1].[h3].allmembers
* [1 Date - Loss Date].[Date].[Year].allmembers
* {[1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120228],[1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120331]}
having [Measures].Total>100000 on rows
from [Monthly Summary]
```

Are you getting the month from a parameter, and therefore looking for a generic way to get the previous month? If so, you can do something like this:

```
select 
    ({ [Measures].[Total]})   on columns,
    non empty
    [Dim1].[h1].allmembers
    * [Dim1].[h2].allmembers
    * [Dim1].[h3].allmembers
    * [1 Date - Loss Date].[Date].[Year].allmembers
    * {[1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120331].PrevMember,[1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120331]}
    having [Measures].Total>100000 on rows
    from [Monthly Summary]
```

UPDATE: 
To get the current value when either the current month or the previous month is greater than 100,000 - regardless of the current month's total, you can do this:

```
select 
    ({ [Measures].[Total]})   on columns,
    non empty
    [Dim1].[h1].allmembers
    * [Dim1].[h2].allmembers
    * [Dim1].[h3].allmembers
    * [1 Date - Loss Date].[Date].[Year].allmembers

    having [Measures].Total>100000 or ([1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120331].PrevMember,  [Measures].Total>100000) on rows
    from [Monthly Summary] 
    where [1 Date - Month End].[Month End Date].[Month].&[20120331]
```

In the HAVING clause, the WHERE clause combines with the measure to filter out any rows not meeting the criteria for the specified month: March 2012. But it does not do this for expression after the OR because the tuple with PrevMember overrides the WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Stacia.  I'm sorry I didn't clearly specify my requirements. In case of "previous" [total]>100k I still need to see the "current" [total] (that might be less than 100k). This query gives the total values more than 100k either in current month or previous month

Comment: I modified my answer based on my current understanding of your requirements.